# Two select statements turn into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have set of two queries. In first query, if is separate from second, I got good results.

First query

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
     SELECT nks.[Id] 
     , nks.[IdNarudzbe]
     , nks.[IdArtikla] as artikal
     , nks.[IdUsluge]
     , nks.[Naziv]
     , nks.Kolicina
    , p.Naziv as kupac
    , p.Id as kupacId
    , p.Adresa
    , p.Telefon
    , nkz.[BrojDokumenta] AS nalog
    , nkz.[BrojDokumentaKroz] AS nalogKroz
    , nkz.[RokIsporuke]
    , nkz.[IdNastaloOdDokumenta]
    , d.Naziv as drzava
    FROM [dbo].[NarudzbaKupacaStavke] nks
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[NarudzbeKupacaZaglavlje] nkz
        ON nkz.Id = nks.IdNarudzbe                            
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Partneri p
        ON nkz.IdKupac = p.Id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Drzave d 
        ON p.IdDrzava = d.Id
    WHERE idArtikla IN ('FP80PUR-08', 'FP80PUR-09', 'FP80PUR-12') 
    AND nkz.[VrstaDokumenta] = 'PRO' 
    AND nkz.StatusArhive = 0 

    --...
```

from first query nkz.[IdNastaloOdDokumenta] is important to second

```
SELECT BrojDokumenta
, BrojDokumentaKroz 
FROM .[dbo].[NarudzbeKupacaZaglavlje]
where id = nkz.[IdNastaloOdDokumenta]
```

For ex. In first query I got `nkz.[IdNastaloOdDokumenta] = 20`. Number 20 I use in second query in where statement, and value I get from `BrojDokumenta`, I would like to join to first query. 
I was wondering if is possible to make one query out of these two. I think I can not union operator because number of column from these two queries don't match.

Comment: The two queries have different columns, effectively different tables, what output do you have in mind here?

Comment: You could try use CTEs and join the results

Comment: As @Valerica states. Put your 2 Select into each CTE and then join them on id = IdNastaloOdDokumenta

Comment: You are already selecting those two column in above query, if you want the results only if this two column are equal id = IdNastaloOdDokumenta then just put the condition in where clause.(where nkz.id = nkz.IdNastaloOdDokumenta )

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want in first query attach another value that I get from second query. For example in first query I got IdNastaloOdDokumenta = 20, From second query I need value from column BrojDokumenta where Id = 20. I was wondering if I can get result in one query, I can solve it on programming side

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The same table, and the same columns are already in the first query. Perhaps you want a self-join, like this:

```
FROM [dbo].[NarudzbaKupacaStavke] nks
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[NarudzbeKupacaZaglavlje] nkz
    ON nkz.Id = nks.IdNarudzbe 

    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[NarudzbeKupacaZaglavlje] nkz2
        ON nkz2.Id = nkz.[IdNastaloOdDokumenta] 

LEFT JOIN dbo.Partneri p
    ON nkz.IdKupac = p.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Drzave d 
    ON p.IdDrzava = d.Id
WHERE idArtikla IN ('FP80PUR-08', 'FP80PUR-09', 'FP80PUR-12') 
AND nkz.[VrstaDokumenta] = 'PRO' 
AND nkz.StatusArhive = 0
```